# Neither dismissViewController or popViewController are working

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller

This should be very straightforward, however I cannot figure it out which is extremely frustrating.

I have 2 view controllers, each embedded in a navigation controller, and on the 2nd VC I have a button which when pressed should dismiss/pop this view and essentially go back. I have tried both of these and neither works:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Help please?

Comment: don't get it --  please improve the question (legibility!)

Comment: seems like its not the issue with the code you have written for the dismiss or pop operation :) May be with the navigation stack

Comment: How did you embedded the navigation controller

Comment: What code are you using in that 1st view controller to go to that 2nd view controller? Could you post that code here? How you go forward is crucial to figuring out how you can go backwards.

Comment: The first VC segues to the 2nd so I did not write any code for this

Comment: At the push of a button in a storyboard?

Comment: I figured it out (again I did the same yesterday)...I am not sure why I embedded the 2nd VC in a nav controller, I changed it to simply a view and then used this code to get what I want: [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

Answer (score 1):

In Case Using Push/Pop navigation scheme :
Make sure you are embedding the navigation controller properly to the view controller from which your navigation starts. 
And also make sure you are using push segue to show the second view controller.

On the other hand : if you are using model segue to present the view controller, no need to embed the navigation controller and this will work

`[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`